# Close alert dialog when background screen changes to other screen

Tags: android, react-native

I am showing an alert dialog using react native code in my android phone.

This will be shown when user clicks a button on the screen.

```
Alert.alert(
  title,
  message,
  [
    {
      text: buttonNegativeText,
      style: 'cancel',
      onPress: () => {
        onNegativePress();
      },
    },
    {
      text: buttonPositiveText,
      style: positiveStyle,
      onPress: () => {
        onPositivePress();
      },
    },
  ],
  {cancelable: cancelable},
);
```

};

And once user leaves the app for 10 seconds(for example), there is an event from native code which will logout the app. When app is getting logged out that means existing screen will be moved and new login screen will be shown.

Whats happening is, the alert dialog is still live in the new screen. i wanted to close the alert dialog when screen moves.

One thing, we can do is, we shall listen the event from native and close the dialog.

But is there a possibility when the current screen moves to other screen and existing screen's alert screen closes automatically.

Not sure whether i am asking the correct question. Pls help.

Comment: You can't dismiss the native Alert programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can't dismiss the native Alert programmatically https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4928

Answer (score 0):

As can seen on [React Native Alert Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert) there is **no way to close the alert programatically**. Also **there is no instance object to handle the alert** dialog from native to react native.

If you really want the Native Alert to be used in your app, You can **create your custom native code** to display the native alert **and from there you can expose the method to hide the current instance** based on some logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to navigations using addListeners and try the **useEffect** like this,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    Alert.alert('', '', []);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

This way we can unsubscribe the Alert notification whenever the navigation occurs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use useIsFocused

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const isFocused = useIsFocused();
 useEffect(() => {
 if (isFocused) {
    // Show the alert when the screen is focused
    Alert.alert('Screen is focused');
 } else {
    // Hide the alert when the screen is unfocused
    Alert.alert('Screen is unfocused');
 }
 // Clean up the alert when the component is unmounted or screen focus changes
 return () => {
  Alert.alert('Clean up');
 };
}, [isFocused]);
```